# How to safely change the names of items in the system settings

Tags: gnome, sound, customization, system-settings

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 15.04, with Gnome Shell, and Gnome 3.14, and in my `gnome-control-center` I have many items, one of which is called `Sound`, now I don't like this name and would like to change it to `Audio Control`, and I would also like to change the image to a custom one, so how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can edit the `.desktop` file corresponding to that item. For `Sound`, it would be `/usr/share/applications/gnome-sound-panel.desktop`. Change the `Name` fields (at least the one corresponding to your locale). For example, the following command would do:

```
sudo sed -i.bak '/^Name/s/Sound/Audio Control/' /usr/share/applications/gnome-sound-panel.desktop
```

To revert, you can copy over the backup file that `sed` made:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/gnome-sound-panel.desktop{.bak,}
```

Effect:

[image]

---

To change the icon, you can edit the `Icon` field in the same file. Just for kicks:

```
sudo sed -i.bak 's/^Icon=.*/Icon=firefox/' /usr/share/applications/gnome-sound-panel.desktop
```

[image]

Comment: What about the image icon?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda same way. Edit the `.desktop` file and change the `Icon` field.

Comment: @muru what desktop background is that?

Comment: @Tim it's the Wheel and Serpent from *The Wheel of Time* series. I don't remember where I got the image from originally, but one link is http://wall.alphacoders.com/big.php?i=603931