# How to change name in top bar for an application in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, configuration, customization, top-bar

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18 and I would like to be able to change the text for an application in the top bar. So for instance how would I change this:

[image]

To just `Firefox`?

Comment: Panda, come on: http://askubuntu.com/q/657007/158442

Comment: @muru: Oh... Well, it's not completely the same... :D

Comment: It does indicate total laziness.

Comment: @muru: [Lazy lifestyle key to pandas' bamboo-only diet](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-33476974).

Comment: @muru: Could you merge the questions or something?

Comment: Sorry, not a mod.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to edit the `.desktop` file.

First, open it in gedit or nano with one of these commands:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
```

<%%>

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
```

Then find the line that says `Name=Firefox Web Browser`, and change it to `Name=Firefox`:

[image]

[image]

Of course, the same works for Google Chrome etc.